# Changing date column with multiple formats to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a date column. It has multiple formats on dates, mostly in 'YYYY-MM-DD' but some 'YYYY.MM.DD' and some like '1968 October 26'. How can i make them into one datetime format? Thanks

Tried a few stack overflow solutions but nothing seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a third party library named `dateparser`. you can read the [docs here](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Here I just show you some examples.

Firstly, just install it by

```
pip install dateparser
```

Then you can do something like:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('2012-10-02')    # YYYY-MM-DD
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 2, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse('2012.05.02')    # YYYY.MM.DD
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 2, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse('1968 October 26')  # Other format 
datetime.datetime(1968, 10, 26, 0, 0)
```

`dateparser.parse` returns Python standard `datetime.datetime`, and you can easily convert it into any format you want.

Besides, I think it may be better if you post "a few stack overflow solutions" and the results so that we can give you some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A parser will convert strings in various formats to Pandas datetime/timestamp. Note dateutil is installed as `python-dateutil`. The datetime/timestamp format is the most suitable for ongoing processing within Pandas. If you do want a string instead then this format can be converted using the `strftime` function which allows the required string format to be defined.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ["2023-10-23", "2011.09.26", "1968 October 26"]})

df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(parse)

print(df)

        Date
0 2023-10-23
1 2011-09-26
2 1968-10-26
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) can handle all those format from scratch, use the parameters `format='mixed', yearfirst=True, dayfirst=False`:

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='mixed',
                             yearfirst=True, dayfirst=False)
```

In this particular case you can even omit `yearfirst=True`:

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='mixed', dayfirst=False)
```

Example:

```
              date      date2
0       1968-10-26 1968-10-26
1       1968.10.26 1968-10-26
2  1968 October 26 1968-10-26
```